# How do I add user inputs to a list with a button?

Tags: c#, list, button, input

Sorry for this noobie Question but I want to have some user Inputs like first Name, last Name and age. When the Person put it all in i want the Inputs to Show up in the list when I hit the submit button. I have no idea how to transfer the Inputs into a list

[This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHCgW.png)

Comment: Do you mean, listbox or a generic list??

Comment: I mean listbox. Sorry if it was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the items directly on your listbox, you can do this on your Button Click Event

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listbox1.Items.Add($"{txtFirstName.Text} {txtLastName.Text} - {txtAge.Text}");
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, you can vote it as the correct answer so the others will know.